# Change the inner text of a link

Tags: jquery

I have tried a couple of different things:

I have dynamic menu, populating parent and sub menus

I need to change the inner text within a link.

```
$("li:has('a'):contains('NAME1')").ReplaceWith('Name2');

$("li:has('a'):contains('NAME1')").text('Name2');
```

None of these seem work as they remove the full link. I dont want to change the link, just the text within the `<a href="linl">name to change</a>`

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.xxxx.com/Sweet-Wines/">

        Fortified & Sweet Wines
```

Comment: If you want to change text of `<a>`, then why do you select `<li>`?

Comment: Hi Regent. Thanks for the reply. The menu is dynamically populated within <LI> elements. There could be multiple name to change values within the body, so i need to target the value within the ul --> li elements only

Comment: ie.  <ul><li><a href="">Name 1</a></li><li><a href="">Name 2</a></li></ul>

Comment: @dale2014 adjusted my answer. Should do the job.

Comment: `$("li a:contains('NAME1')").text('Name2');` if you want to check for `NAME1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
 <ul class="js-my-menu">
    <li><a href="somelink">Name1</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Then you can use

```
$('.js-my-menu').find('a:contains("Name1")').text('new text');
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6w8zpz3r/2/

**Note,** the `js-` prefix in the class name is a best practice approach for highlighting classes that are only used as a hook for attaching JavaScript behavior and should rather not be used for styling purposes. That improves maintainability.

Comment: Thank you Juri. THat works perfect my friend. Thanks to everyone that posted. Great work guys,

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work:
given html:

```
<a href="somelink">Text</a>
```

and .js:

```
$('a').text('new text');
```

this works. [check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6w8zpz3r/)

you might have the wrong selector? post more HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the HTML from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278176/change-the-inner-text-of-a-link/26278463#comment41228572_26278176):

`$("li:has('a'):contains('NAME1')").text('Name2');` is almost correct, but you are selecting wrong element (`li`, instead of `a`).

You can simply do this instead:

```
$("li:contains('NAME 1') a").text('Name 2');
```

---

### Demo:

```js
$("li:contains('Name 1') a").text('Changed text')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Name 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Name 2</a></li>
</ul>
```